# Get the list of all files under the folder resources

Tags: java, junit

My unit test project structure looks like this:

```
.
└── src
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── foo
        │       └── MyTest.java
        └── resources
            ├── file1
            |-- ...
            └── fileN
```

In **MyTest.java**, I would like to get a list of all files under `src/test/resources/` :

```
File[] files = GET_ALL_RESOURCE_FILES();
```

how to do it in Java?

Comment: Try this `File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/");File[] files = folder.listFiles();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as your code:

```
File Selected_Folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/");
File[] list_of_files = Selected_Folder.listFiles();
```

For viewing the files under that particular directory from where you have selected the files... you can do this...

```
for(int i=0; i<list_of_files.length; i++)
 {
   System.out.println(" File Number "+(i+1)+" = "+list_of_files[i]);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

My Approach--

```
  File[] GET_ALL_RESOURCE_FILES(final File file)
    {
    java.util.List<File> ls = new ArrayList<File>();
                    for (final File fileIter : file.listFiles())  {
                if (fileIter.isDirectory())
                    loadAll(fileIter);
                else
                    ls.add(fileIter);

            }
return ls.toArray();}
```

Now call this function--

```
File[] files = GET_ALL_RESOURCE_FILES('src/test/resources/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `File folder = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/");
File[] files = folder.listFiles();`

`System.getProperty("user.dir")` will return path of your current working directory. In maven projects it returns path of your maven project folder which is parent folder of src folder.

Comment: should work, but it would be better if subfolders would be treated as folders with files to extract.